# Get AndroidManifest.xml from phone?

Tags: android, android-manifest, recovery

I destroyed my local copy of the `AndroidManifest.xml`. I still have the rest of the code and the application is installed on my phone. Any chance to recover the xml file from the phone?

Comment: I'm staggered at how many people with the brains to develop software don't have the brains to backup stuff they care about. Sorry, just saying. It is probably much easier to recreate it than to try to recover it - but there are tools out there to do so - Google will show several.

Comment: I recommend using this decompiler https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dexplorer

Comment: it's a private project I just started today and GIT should have followed ;-) well, anyway, I tried dexplorer and it shows the manifest, but there seems to be no copy option? My manifest isn't that long, yet I would prefer not to duplicate it manually ):

Answer (score 0):

you can use App Saver from Google Play for get your APK, and after that use apk to java for get Manifest

Answer (score 0):

Use this app - [Dexplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dexplorer). You can see your whole code.